# jQuery on click function not working in Android mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

This jQuery onclick function works perfectly in all computer browsers but when run on Android mobile devices' default browser it doesn't. It does work in Chrome mobile browser.

### html

```
<input type="button" value="Add" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
<div class="table-responsive " style= "max-width:900px;">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width:20px">#</th>
        <th>code</th>
        <th>credit</th>
        <th>Grade</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tableBody">
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

### js

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var i=0;
        var code;
        var credit=0;
        var grade=0;


        $('#submit').click(function (){
            i=i+1;
            code=$('input[name=codeInput]').val();
            credit=$('select[name=quantity]').val();
            grade=$('select[name=gradetInput]').val();
            $('.tableBody').append( '<tr class="trow">'+'<td>' + i +'</td>'+'<td>' + code +'</td>'+'<td>' + credit +'</td>'+'<td>' + grade +'</td>'+'</tr>');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

try use touchstart, like this:

```
$('#submit').bind('touchstart click', function(){
    i=i+1;
    code=$('input[name=codeInput]').val();
    credit=$('select[name=quantity]').val();
    grade=$('select[name=gradetInput]').val();
    $('.tableBody').append( '<tr class="tenter code hererow">'+'<td>' + i +'</td>'+'<td>' + code +'</td>'+'<td>' + credit +'</td>'+'<td>' + grade +'</td>'+'</tr>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick

```
$(function() {
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
});
```

profit, but hey what is `i` in your code?

Comment: sorry "i" is Counter i forget declare it  here

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this is an issue, but try adding this rule:

```
.dropdown-backdrop {
 z-index: -1;
}
```